# Drupal broken after upgrade to CiviCRM 4.6.16

Tags: drupal, upgrade

Site was happily working under 4.6.15 - ** Running Drupal 6 ** - Drupal 6 broken after upgrade.

Every time (Tried 3 times now) I try to upgrade in my development environment I get this message:

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare phptemplate_preprocess_page() (previously declared in /srv/bindings/619ae4403404445daf26537c92800797/code/sites/all/themes/*****custom_theme_name_changed_to_protect_id_of_website****/drupal6_theme_methods.php:8) in /srv/bindings/619ae4403404445daf26537c92800797/code/themes/garland/template.php on line 42

I've renamed the path above to my custom template to protect the id of the website concerned.

Any ideas anyone? 4.6.16 has security patch(es) so I'm under pressure to upgrade. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that error is related to your CiviCRM upgrade, at least not directly. That error message is telling you that a duplicate function exists in your custom theme's `drupal6_theme_methods.php` file and garland's `template.php` file. Neither of those files are in the CiviCRM directory, which is the only code you replaced during the upgrade, right?

Comment: Yes. I'm 100% sure it was just the upgrade files.....because it's hosted on Pantheon, I could even track only the changes in the sites/all/modules/civicrm directory using git - and it still breaks. ALso, please bear in mind, that I was on 4.6.14 - an upgrade to 4.6.16 breaks...I then used the exact same method to get it to 4.6.15 with no problems. It only does this to me in 4.6.16 - I admit it's most strange.